# Spring Data JPA duplicate entires

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I have a customer table and an Address table in mysql. Structure as follows:

```
customer:{customer_id, name, email, shipping_address_id, mailing_address_id}
address:{address_id, street_name, suburb, state, postcode}
```

`shipping_address_id, mailing_address_id` are foreign keys in the customer table which reference the `address_id` in the address table.

`shipping_address_id, mailing_address_id` have a `@OneToOne` uni-directional relation to the `address_id`.

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "shipping_address_id")
private Address shippingAddress;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "billing_address_id")
private Address billingAddress;
```

I have managed to write a rest endpoint where I can insert data into these tables with the following payload:

```
{
    "name": "testName",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "shippingAddress": {
        "streetAddress": "Strert1",
        "suburb": "TestSuburb",
        "state": "TestState",
        "postcode": "TestPostcode"
    }, 
    "mailingAddress": {
        "streetAddress": "Strert1",
        "suburb": "TestSuburb",
        "state": "TestState",
        "postcode": "TestPostcode"
    }
}
```

The only problem is when the shipping_address and mailing address are the same, it inserts the Address twice. Is there a way to check first before inserting a record in address?. If the address exists, is it possible to link the existing address to the customer?

Happy to provide code for mapping if needed. I have not defined any Specifications on the CrudRepository.save method

**Edit: Implemented as per suggestion from m.aibin**

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/customer", method = POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> addCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
    try {

        customerService.createCustomer(customer);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Error creating the user: " + ex.toString(), INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>("User succesfully created! (id = " + customer.getCustomerId() + ")", OK);
}
```

Service

```
public void createCustomer(Customer customer) {
    if(customer.getBillingAddress().equals(customer.getShippingAddress())){
        customer.setShippingAddress(null);
        Customer savedCustomer = customerRepository.save(customer);
        customer.setShippingAddress(savedCustomer.getBillingAddress());
        customerRepository.save(customer);
    }
    else {
        customerRepository.save(customer);
    }
}
```

It works :) . Just wondering if there is a Specification based method to implement this where i can do something similar to?

```
customerRepository.save(modifiedSave(customer))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no restriction for columns to be not null, you can do following:

1. Check if addresses are the same
2. If they are, save your Customer object without Mailing address object (this method can for example return Address object). Then set Address object to customer as Mailing id and update Customer object in DB.
3. If values are not the same, just do one save.

Hope you understand my way of thinking ;)

Comment: I am a bit confused around the second step. My objects are being populated by Spring serialization. I could in the controller check if the shipping address is same as the mailing address. I dont have a not null restriction on the table, so i could save the Customer object to the DB with no mailing address. How do i then tell Spring Data Jpa to set the mailing ID in the customer object. I have editted the question with my @OneToOne mapping. no mailing_Id field in customer object

Comment: when you save your object, you can return it from a JPA method. Then for returned object get the address_id from shipping and set it as a mailing as well. Then perform update.

Comment: I have edited after implementing m.abibin's suggestion. it works great. Just wondering if there is a Specification based method to implement this